# When we open-circuit the secondary side of a transformer, why can we ignore the series impedance on the primary side?

Tags: transformer

I know no current flows through the secondary side (which lets us ignore the series components), but why would that enable us to ignore the series resistive & reactive components on the primary side?

[image]

Comment: What series components, could you be more specific?

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for the quick response -- please see the blue circle in the following image: https://imgur.com/a/NFo4wzb

Comment: Please add details by editing your post -- thanks!

Comment: No problem, done!

Comment: What's your understanding of this circuit -- did you find it, were you told to use it, have you derived it yourself, etc.? Are you familiar with non-ideal transformers?

Comment: Rp&Rs represents the power losses in the respective windings, Lp&s represents the leakage inductances in their respective windings. Lm is the core inductance and Rc is the core losses. Doing an internship and found a similar image on a company slide for calculating leakage reactance (didn't go into much detail, though).  Finished my circuits classes 2-3 years ago, don't remember much about non-ideal transformers 

Comment: we can't always ignore them, it depends on the magnitude of the magnetising inductance. For many low frequency good quality transformers, they have a negligible effect and so can be ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typical real general-purpose transformers have | Lm || Xc | >> | Lp + Rp | so you can consider Lp + Rp a short for the purposes of approximately determining the magnetizing current and the output voltage.

Comment: Thanks very much Spehro

Answer (score 4):

> *I know no current flows through the secondary side (which lets us
> ignore the series components), but why would that enable us to ignore
> the series resistive & reactive components on the primary side?*

The series components \$L_P\$ and \$R_P\$ on the primary side are still passing magnetization current into \$L_M\$ therefore, those series components produce a volt-drop.

Hence, in many situations **we don't** ignore them.